# Ruby: %{x} vs. #{x}?

Tags: ruby

I understand that calling a variable inside a string by using `%{x}` instead of `#{x}` applies the same format to multiple variables. Can someone elaborate?

Comment: Can you provide the context where `%{x}` and `#{x}` is used. It would help in answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Small self explanatory Example:

```
2.1.1 :009 > x=10
 => 10 
2.1.1 :010 > "num is #{x}"
 => "num is 10" 
2.1.1 :011 > "num is %{x}"
 => "num is %{x}" 
2.1.1 :012 >
```

`#{x}` is interpolation of var `x` inside a string; this is handy construct in Ruby to replace the string concat. Here, Ruby executes `.to_s` method in the object we pass viz. here `x`; `x.to_s` is invoked before it is concated.

For `%{x}` this construct is used in `I18n` implementation in Rails. Value of `x` is set while calling the translate method `.t(:some_symbol, x: some_value)`

Answer (score 0):

The %{} is used with the % method of strings, in which case it uses a Hash as argument.

```
h = {x: "three", y: "Hi"}
p "%{y}, num is %{x}." % h # => "Hi, num is three."
```